# BASH Regular Expression {} confusion

Tags: regex, bash

I think I have the wrong idea of how the `{3,5}` portion works.

From my understanding, it is specifying a range that the digits have to comply to return a search result?

For instance, `3,5` means 3-5 digits to return a search. Upon some experimentation, I have realized that my logic is not exactly correct.

It seems to apply up from 3-5 characters, and then 8,9 and ten characters.

Am I missing a pattern here? Or more simply, can someone explain to me the logic behind that? Is it simply multiples of 3, or 5? including the range of 3-5? Really confused here. Thanks!

> user@matrix:~> echo 1234567891234 | grep '[0-9]{3,5}'
>
> 1234567891234

The above matched successfully, it contained 12 characters...

Comment: `grep --line-regexp '[0-9]\{3,5\}'`?

Comment: If you don't anchor your match, it applies only to a substring -- meaning, in this case, that you have 3-5 characters ANYWHERE WITHIN YOUR LARGER STRING. It sounds like you want `^[0-9]\{3,5\}$`.

Comment: This has nothing with Bash to do, by the way. While Bash also has built-in regex capabilities, they behave rather differently from `grep`'s, which you are examining here.

Comment: @nosid `--line-regexp` is a synonym for `-x` (or vice versa) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-o` option to visualize how grep works:

```
echo 1234567891234 | grep -o '[0-9]\{3,5\}'
```

Output:

```
12345
67891
234
```

`-o` will add a new line after each match to output. Without that option, grep will just print the whole line where the match(es) happend - what will be the input string itself again. This way you won't be able to see how grep exactly matched the string.

But now you can see that grep found multiple matches in that line 2 times a 5 digit string and 1 times a 3 digit string.

Also you need slashes in front of the `{}` brackets unless you are using the `-E` option.

Comment: Well... the matches is not what `grep` normally outputs, the _entire line_ is what goes to stdout, which means that for `123456789123` (matches twice, but can't do anything with the last 2 chars) still the entire line will go to output. So, it's not 'merging matches', it's telling the line matched at least one time.

Comment: @Wrikken I know that, but it appears like this

Comment: Well, it makes your answer quite ambiguous. As a newbee, I'd read it as: all matches go to stdout without a newline, just add an `-o` in there to add a separator. I'd avoid making it so easy misunderstanding the answer.

Comment: @Wrikken I have updated this. However I don't think that my post was dramatically misleading. At least I'm the only one who mentioned `-o`

Comment: 1) you haven't answered the actual question 2) `-o` is irrelevant here. nice tool for debugging, add it as a comment...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Please explain. Note that the question is about understanding, having the output from `-o` it is easy to understand what is going on. And no, I will not drop a comment with multi-line output.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in the assumption that {3,5} is defining a repetition of the characters chosen in the class that's preceding it - between 3 to 5 (both inclusive) repetitions.
You can also do something like `{3,}` which means - "at least 3 times"

Use `-Ex` options, `E` - so you won't have to use the slash before the brackets and `x` in order to mach the whole line:

```
[alfasin@otrs ~]$ echo 1234567891234 | grep -Ex '[0-9]{3,5}'
[alfasin@otrs ~]$ echo 1234567891234 | grep -Ex '[0-9]{3,13}'
1234567891234
```

From grep manual:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>                 Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
>
> -x, --line-regexp
>                 Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: You should not have edited the question if you are now answering with `-E` I already had an answer with `-E` but have changed it after your edit.

Comment: @hek2mgl I started my answer with -E (and when I started your answer had the -o) and later on I added the `x`. Also - I was using `grep` while your answer used `egrep`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm not sure if I got what you meant - but just in case I added the first paragraph to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's working exactly as you've written it:

```
grep '[0-9]\{3,5\}'  - Is there 3 to 5 sequential numeric characters in this string?
```

If the string is `1234567891234`, there is a sub-string in there that contains 3 - 5 numeric characters.

If you are only interested in strings that only contain 3 - 5 numeric characters and no more than 5 characters, you have to put some boundaries in your regular expression. You should also use the `-E` flag which uses the more modern version of the regular expressions:

```
$ echo 12345678901234 | grep -E "(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{3,5}([^0-9]|$)"
```

This will not print anything, but this will:

```
$ echo 1234 | grep -E "(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{3,5}([^0-9]|$)"
```

And this:

```
$ echo 12345aaa6789aaa01234 | grep -E "(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{3,5}([^0-9]|$)"
```

The first `(^|[^0-9])` says *either at the beginning of the line* (That's the leading `^`), *or anything besides the characters 0-9*. (That's the `[^0-9]`). Using the `(...|...)` in an extended regular expression means *either the expression on the left or the expression on the right*. The same goes for the ending `([^0-9]|$)` which says either non numerics or the end of a line.

In the middle is your `[0-9]{3,5}` (no backslash needed for the extended expression). This says between 3 to 5 digits. And, since it is bound on either side by non-digits, or the beginning or end of the string, this will do what you want.

A couple of things:

```
$ echo 12345aaa6789aaa01234 | grep -E "(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{3,5}([^0-9]|$)"
```

and

```
$ grep -E "(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{3,5}([^0-9]|$)" <<<"12345aaa6789aaa01234"
```

Mean pretty much the same thing. However, the second is more efficient since only a single process has to run, and there's no piping. Plus, it's shorter to type.

Also, you can use (and it's preferred to use) character classes:

$ grep -E "(^|[^[[:digit:]])[[:digit:]]{3,5}([^[:digit:]]|$)"<<<"12345aaa6789aaa01234"

This will allow your regular expression to work even if you aren't in a place that uses Latin alphanumeric characters. This is a shorter way to do the same since `\d` is the same class as `[:digit:]`:

```
$ grep -E "(^|[^\d])\d{3,5}([^\d]|$)"<<<"12345aaa6789aaa01234"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use that particular regular expression, it's matching the first 5 characters in the input string (see [http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=[0-9]{3%2C5}&input=1234567891234%0A](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B0-9%5D%7B3,5%7D&input=1234567891234%0A) for a visualization).  Once `grep` finds a match, it stops processing and returns the matching line.  It's not even paying attention to anything beyond that match.

If you are looking for something to match only isolated sequences of *exactly* 3-5 digits, try a regex like:

```
\b[0-9]{3,5}\b
```

The '`\b`' will match a word boundary, meaning a transition between a word character (letter, digit, etc) and a non-word character (whitespace, punctuation, etc).  This would generate a match for `1234`, but not `12` or `1234567891234`.

You can also use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as a more powerful way to make sure that your match has no numerals before and after it.  grep's support for lookaround doesn't appear to be complete, however, so you may have to use something like perl instead.